# "bear replacement with"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> In general, unless you’re going for a formal tone, to wit **bears replacement with** one of the many alternatives, such as namely, specifically, in other words, more precisely, or to clarify. ([source](https://grammarist.com/usage/to-wit/))

I am assuming the phrase "bear replacement with" is used here to mean "can be used interchangeably with", but it seems to be a non-idiomatic phrase. Does this phrase really exist? Google seems to suggest it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bear" can be used to mean "support" or "accept". If we say "to wit" bears replacement with "namely" or "specifically" etc, we mean that usage and meaning support or accept such a replacement. Compare with "bear comparison with", "bear scrutiny", etc.

> 2.2 Be able to accept or stand up to. ‘it is doubtful whether either of these distinctions would bear scrutiny’

[Bear (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bear)